# Need help for a sentence!

Tags: grammaticality

I am trying to make this sentence but I am not sure if this is grammatically correct? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the sentence.

- ''Therefore I had bought my first car in December 2011 so that I could go to my work and to my university as well''.

I am trying to explain the reason why it was necessary for me to buy a car that I had bought 4 years ago. Also can someone explain if ''could'' is ok in this sentence.

Comment: You should ask this on the site ELL. "to work" and "to university"  is better.

Comment: Note that rogermue's suggestion is that you resubmit this question at our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: O.K. Thank you rogermue and sven yargs. I only wanted to get a quick reply for my question that's why I resubmitted my question on ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of *could* is correct. It expresses **ability** in the past.

The use of *therefore*, however, sounds odd here. Unless everything that follows *therefore* is the reason for something in a sentence preceding this one, it should not be there.

I am guessing that *so that I could go to work and university as well* is the reason for buying the car. The conjunction *so* already expresses this, which means you do not need therefore. It links your first sentence (buying the car) to your goal (being able to go to work...).

> I had bought my first car in December 2011 **so** that I could go to work and to university as well.

You can also use a synonym for *so* if you want to stress the goal just a little more:

> I had bought my first car in December 2011 **in order to** be able to go to work and to university as well.

Or you could leave out *so* and split the sentence, using *therefore* to introduce the second sentence:

> I wanted to be able to go to work and to university as well. **Therefore** I had bought first car in December 2011.

Note that I left out *my* before *work* and *university* to make your sentence more idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you so much Sander. I really appreciate you for giving such a brief answer.